# Posting Data to another Page ExtJs

Tags: extjs, modx

I'm trying to post an array using a POST request to a specific page, the target page generates a csv and send me back the stream, right now i'm doing using ExtJs Ajax class, but that won't work as i need to make a normal HTTP request not ajax, my current code is as follows:

```
Ext.extend(Players.panel.Home,MODx.Panel,{
    exportSubscribers: function(btn,e) {
            MODx.Ajax.request({
                url: Players.config.connectorUrl 
                ,params: {
                    action: 'mgr/player/getSubscribers'
                }

            });
        }
});
```

The exportSubscribers function is executed from a normal ExtJs button

```
{ xtype: 'button'
  ,text: 'Export Subscribers'
  ,preventRender: true
  ,handler: this.exportSubscribers
    }
```

What class should i use to turn this into a normal request?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a class to do a *normal request*. I known two ways to accomplish a file download:

- Use a hidden form in the page, replace the field values and invoke the form's `.sumbit` method from ExtJS button handler to do the POST request you want.
- Replace your button by an HTTP anchor if you can use a GET request to make the server return the file: `<a href="url?params" title="Download CSV">Download CSV</a>'`

Comment: i tried the first approach, faced another issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7068191/getting-the-form-to-submit-when-clicking-the-submit-button

Answer (score 0):

You'd be better off making a local request to your server, and then in your server-side code make a cURL request to the CSV source. That way, you can make a non XMLHttpRequest method to get your data.

Comment: am generating the csv source on the file, the question is how to execute the file handling the generation through a normal HTTP POST and not ajax, i think i should put the button in a form with a submit action

Comment: why do you need to make a regular request?

Comment: so i can freely change the HTTP header and return the csv stream, from what I understand i can't return something like that in an AJAX request, right?